# SQL Server 2012 using codes instead of design (TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and I want to create tables using SQL codes(TSQL) instead of designing the table, I saw tutorial on how to do this but when I try to open the file of the table it gives me this message:

[image]

Comment: Error is pretty clear. Did you check if the file exists? Do you have permissions to open the file? You might want to change them.

Comment: @Consider Me yes the file exist and I want to change the permissions from where I can change it ?

Comment: That's totally different question. There are also tutorials for this depending on your OS.

Answer (score -2):

I solve it, its very simple all I needed to do is right click the file it choose select top 200 and it will open tsql.